# Pigeonhole problem - salvaging my solution

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A student is solving combinatorics problems. Each day he solves at least one problem. He solves no more than 500 problems a year. Prove that there is an interval of days in which he solves 229 problems.

This is my approach.Lets consider partial sums. A(x) is a sum of problems after x days. Now what is the remainder of A(x) and 229? A(x) changes as days go by, there are only 229 possible remainders and 365 days - so there must be two days x and y, where A(x) and A(y) have the same remainder. A(x) and A(y) represent sums of problems of two overlapping periods. A(x) is the larger period (you can assume this). A(x)-A(y) is divisible by 229 and is positive. A(x)-A(y) also represents a sum of problems of a certain period (since the two periods are overlapping, just take the larger period and disregard the part of the larger period that is the smaller period.

However, I can only show that A(x)-A(y) is divisible by 229, I didnt show that A(x)-A(y) = 229. Is there any way how I can salvage my approach?

Comment: Is the first $299$ a typo?  Later you are using $229$.  You could also see [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571937/combinatorics-pigeonhole-problem)

Comment: yes, the correct number 229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other value for $A(x)-A(y)$ is $458$, because we know it is less than $500$.  Repeat your argument for the first $310$ days of the year, as he must have done less than $458$ problems in that span.

Comment: You say to "repeat my argument", but if I use the argument with 310 days, isnt a large part of the previous answer rendered superfluous?

Comment: I meant it as a way to give a complete answer.  If you say in 310 days he has done a maximum of 445 problems, and there must be a span where he did a multiple of 229 problems you are home.